# Why Google Webmaster tools showing index status 0?

Tags: post

I've added my site to Google Webmaster tools kanosa.com. The site was submitted a few months ago. The index status shows 0 but it shows multiple URLs have been indexed in the sitemaps section. If I search in google I can see that the site is indexed and several pages appear:

Comment: Index status often seriously lags. It can be horribly incorrect as a result. If you submit a sitemap, then you may get better results. The question is, how big is your site? I would expect this result for smaller sites. As well, is this a new site? New sites, especially smaller sites, take quite a while to settle into the index and for webmaster tools to reflect reality.

Comment: Additionally you are using canonical without the www. so index 0 with www is right. Add your site to Webmaster Tools without (www). also doing a site://yourdomain.com without the www will return lots of indexed pages. Additionally look at 'Thin' content. User Generated content unless your the next Gumtree(authority) takes ages to index.